# Share using UIActivityController with more available options

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode7, uiactivityviewcontroller

I was trying to share some text on `Facebook` and `Twitter` via my App. I searched and I found a piece of code to do that and it's doing well, however I can't understand the compiler response as it looks that there's something wrong.
the code is

```
NSArray *objectTOShare = @[_TweetTextView.text];

UIActivityViewController *activity = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]initWithActivityItems:objectTOShare applicationActivities:nil];

NSArray *excludeActivities = @[];

activity.excludedActivityTypes = excludeActivities;

[self presentViewController:activity animated:YES completion:nil];
```

As far as I can understand, as I excluded nothing so all the available options should appear like message and AirDrop for example. yet, only mail, facebook, and twitter only appear. Can any one explain to me why that happens.

[image: The App response]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's normal those are the only available options on a Simulator, try running it in a real device and you should get message and Airdrop...

Comment: I don't know about those, not all the applications appears there, You can add a custom entry  by creating a custom UIActivity. But for message and Airdrop they already appear by default on a real device.

Answer (score 1):

There is **More** option(nearer to available activities) to enable other activities
[image]

Comment: I have an error message from xcode that I don't have a registered device in the Member Centre and I don't know how to fix it, can you help with that?

Comment: Yes you need to do provisioning to run on device. or check this [blog](http://www.wastedpotential.com/running-xcode-projects-on-a-device-without-a-developer-account-in-xcode-7/) you can even run without paid member account

Comment: woohoo I did it, it works now and I have all the share options there!